# Is bone cp or mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection known for leaking?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, connection-pooling

We have been using bone cp for pooling purposes. What we notice via the mat result is that its pointing to this com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection and the memory usage keep increasing? Below are 2 samples where we can see the increase in the memory usage.

Sample 1

```
21 instances of "com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection", loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader @ 0xf000a4f0" occupy 11,793,200 (76.19%) bytes. 

Biggest instances:

•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf016d728 - 958,096 (6.19%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf0094478 - 875,568 (5.66%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf0201ba0 - 816,048 (5.27%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf04ab3f0 - 754,016 (4.87%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf006ee40 - 727,024 (4.70%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf0076a90 - 663,872 (4.29%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf04ad490 - 618,200 (3.99%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf00b7bd0 - 616,608 (3.98%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf0467bc0 - 612,544 (3.96%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf015fcf0 - 598,400 (3.87%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf021c830 - 584,992 (3.78%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf0097818 - 561,224 (3.63%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf01a27c0 - 531,816 (3.44%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf00bea28 - 531,416 (3.43%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf01c2d80 - 522,184 (3.37%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf04693e0 - 482,992 (3.12%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf012b158 - 453,256 (2.93%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf147f438 - 424,656 (2.74%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf15ff7d0 - 187,008 (1.21%) bytes. 


Keywords
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader @ 0xf000a4f0
 Reference Pattern
Class Name Shallow Heap Retained Heap Percentage 
class java.lang.Thread @ 0xf0003840 40 208 0.00
```

Sample 2

```
21 instances of "com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection", loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader @ 0xf000a4f0" occupy 17,339,632 (80.79%) bytes. 

Biggest instances:

•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf016d728 - 1,228,048 (5.72%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf0094478 - 1,144,056 (5.33%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf0201ba0 - 1,126,120 (5.25%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf04ab3f0 - 1,074,552 (5.01%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf006ee40 - 993,912 (4.63%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf0076a90 - 931,512 (4.34%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf015fcf0 - 930,952 (4.34%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf04ad490 - 918,176 (4.28%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf00bea28 - 874,512 (4.07%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf0467bc0 - 846,368 (3.94%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf00b7bd0 - 838,448 (3.91%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf021c830 - 799,184 (3.72%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf0097818 - 791,256 (3.69%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf01a27c0 - 763,264 (3.56%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf01c2d80 - 745,088 (3.47%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf012b158 - 710,704 (3.31%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf04693e0 - 704,072 (3.28%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf147f438 - 680,400 (3.17%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf1603618 - 458,472 (2.14%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf148fd70 - 390,984 (1.82%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf15ff7d0 - 389,552 (1.82%) bytes. 


Keywords
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader @ 0xf000a4f0
 Reference Pattern
Class Name Shallow Heap Retained Heap Percentage 
class java.lang.Thread @ 0xf0003840 40 208 0.00%
```

Sample shallow and retained heap

```
Class Name                                                       |   Objects | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                 |           |              |              
byte[]                                                           |    19,197 |    4,502,128 |     4,502,128
char[]                                                           |    50,285 |    2,646,080 |     2,646,080
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet                                    |     9,427 |    1,659,152 |    12,354,360
java.util.HashMap$Entry[]                                        |    19,246 |    1,641,928 |    16,387,720
java.lang.String                                                 |    51,067 |    1,634,144 |     3,951,064
com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl                                     |     9,427 |    1,432,904 |    15,295,672
java.util.TreeMap                                                |    28,285 |    1,357,680 |     2,495,568
com.mysql.jdbc.Field                                             |     9,417 |    1,356,048 |     2,485,064
java.util.TreeMap$Entry                                          |    28,420 |    1,136,800 |     1,137,856
java.util.HashMap                                                |    19,224 |      922,752 |    16,401,088
java.util.HashMap$Entry                                          |    22,253 |      712,096 |    16,255,280
java.lang.Object[]                                               |    10,789 |      593,000 |     1,412,184
java.lang.Object                                                 |    20,583 |      329,328 |       329,328
com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataStatic                                     |     9,417 |      301,344 |     1,054,704
java.net.SocksSocketImpl                                         |     2,572 |      288,064 |       836,096
java.util.ArrayList                                              |     9,729 |      233,496 |       830,136
com.mysql.jdbc.Field[]                                           |     9,427 |      226,168 |     2,711,224
byte[][]                                                         |     9,417 |      226,008 |       452,648
com.mysql.jdbc.ByteArrayRow                                      |     9,417 |      226,008 |       678,656
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$BooleanConnectionProperty|     2,750 |      176,000 |       179,520
java.util.Hashtable$Entry                                        |     4,837 |      154,784 |       295,040
java.util.HashSet                                                |     9,460 |      151,360 |     1,372,632
Total: 22 of 2,427 entries; 2,405 more                           |   407,563 |   23,597,568 |              
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For  insert and update queries we do this and below we make sure closed the statement.

```
 Statement stmt1 = null;
stmt1 = dbconn.createStatement();
String insertQuery3 =........
count = stmt9.executeUpdate(insertQuery3);
try{
   if ( stmt1!= null ){  stmt1.close();
}
   else{
   System.out.println("No stm1 exist");

}
}catch(SQLException ex){   System.out.println("SQLException has been caught for stmt1");
ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
}

For select we do this  

Statement stmt2 = null;
stmt2 = dbconn.createStatement(); 
String selectQuery2= .........
ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(selectQuery2);

if(rs2.next())
{

}
try{
   if ( rs2!= null ){  rs2.close();
   }   else{
   System.out.println("No rs2 exist");

}

   if ( stmt2!= null ){  stmt2.close();
   }   else{
   System.out.println("No stm2 exist");

}
}catch(SQLException ex){   System.out.println("SQLException has been caught for stmt2");
ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

Comment: It is more likely that your code is leaking connections.

Comment: @Jim I have added more information in my question on how I close and just to add towards the end I do close my connection too. In addition I have put up a table whichs shows the shallow heap and reatined heap? How interpret on this ?

Comment: @new14 Have you found a solution to this issue? I am too facing the same issue where JDBC4ResultSet is occupying more memory.