# Java memory leak caused by MySQL libraries

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, memory-leaks

I have a thread that executes and updates a database with some values. I commented out all the operations done to the data and just left the lines you can see below. While running the program with the lines you see bellow I get a memory leak.

This is what it looks like in VisualVM

[image]
[image]
Mysql Class

```
    public ResultSet executeQuery(String Query) throws SQLException {
        statement = this.connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(Query);
        return resultSet;

    }



    public void executeUpdate(String Query) throws SQLException {
        Statement tmpStatement = this.connection.createStatement();
        
        tmpStatement.executeUpdate(Query);
        tmpStatement.close();
        tmpStatement=null;
        
    }
```

Thread file

```
public void run() {
        ResultSet results;
        String query;
        int id;
        String IP;
        int port;
        String SearchTerm;
        int sleepTime;
        while (true) {
            try {

                query = "SELECT * FROM example WHERE a='0'";
                results = this.database.executeQuery(query);

                while (results.next()) {
                    
                    id = results.getInt("id");
                
                    query = "UPDATE example SET a='1' WHERE id='"
                            + id + "'";
                    SearchTerm=null;
                    this.database.executeUpdate(query);
                }
                results.close();
                results = null;
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

The problem has happened with many other people after researching the web,

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=987128

[Is bone cp or mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection known for leaking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480639/is-bone-cp-or-mysql-jdbc-jdbc4connection-known-for-leaking)

and a few more if you google "jdbc4resultset memory leak"

Comment: How does each individual thread acquire it's `Connection` object? Good chance the issue is there

Comment: creating a new statement each time is a lot of overhead. look into `PreparedStatement` to reduce overhead (both processing and network), increase performance, and improve safety (automatically escapes database-specific keywords to guard against SQL Injection).

Comment: It looks like you are leaking `ResultSet` instances. You could take a heap dump and see where they're being held onto.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have something wrong somewhere... I use the mysql jdbc 4.0 driver daily (actually thousands of times a day since it's in production code) and don't have any leaks known to be caused by it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The leak is yours, not MySQL's. You aren't closing the statement.

The design of your method is poor. It should close the statement, and it should return something that will survive closing of the statement, such as a `CachedRowSet`.

Or else it should not exist at all. It's only three lines, and it doesn't support query parameters, so it isn't really much use. I would just delete it.

You also appear to have `statement` as an instance member, which is rarely if ever correct. It should be local to the method. At present your code isn't even thread-safe.

You should also be closing the `ResultSet` in a finally block to ensure it gets closed. Ditto the `Statement`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are explicitly closing the database connections.